# persistant connections and max_user_connections

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need some info as soon as you can to help me sort out an issue. I have designed an application in PHP which queries a mysql database and returns responses as json. I have load tested the json response in both pylot and apache jmeter and it was fine. I am using persistent connections using PHP's PDO. However even though the connection is persistent I am still getting denied connections to the database with the following error.

```
[23-Apr-2013 12:11:53] SQLSTATE[42000] [1203] User user already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
```

I had thought that persistent connections would mitigate this but it looks like they are being ignored. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
$DBH = null;

$host = "localhost";
$db_name = "my_db";
$user_name = "user";
$pass_word = "password";

try {
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8", $user_name, $pass_word, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    error_log( $e->getMessage(), 0 );
}
```

Comment: Do you have more apache connections than max_user_connections? (high load or such thing?)

Comment: dropping persistence will sort out the problem http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/12/are-php-persistent-connections-evil/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention was to reduce number of connections, using pconnect would be wrong idea, as it will actually increase the number.

So, to solve the problem you have to increase the number of max_user_connections in mysql server configuration to match the number of apache threads/nginx workers.

If you can't increase number of max_user_connections,  you shouldn't use persistent connection then.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience over the years, persistent connections in PHP scripts do not mitigate the *max_user_connection* error message. On the contrary, they're often the *cause*.

Whatever the reason, connection pooling is not working as advertised. PHP tends to open new connections even when there're idle ones sitting there. As a result, a relatively low traffic app ends up exhausting the maximum (and 90% of the connections are doing nothing).

If the feature exists, there must be an scenario where it works properly. Perhaps the issue is that it only works correctly on certain platforms or SAPIs. Whatever, I suggest you *disable* persistent connections and monitor your app.